# Replace columns using a shell

Tags: sed, awk

How could I replace column 1 in `File1` with column 2 in `File2`, when a match is found?

```
File1
id1 36987
id2 75685
id3 12345
id4 12896

File2
id1 ID1
id2 ID2
id3 ID3
id5 ID5
```

I'd like to write this on another `File3`, that should look like:

```
File3
ID1 36987
ID2 75685
ID3 12345
id4 12896
```

I'm currently (unsuccessfully) trying:

```
sed `File2.txt | awk '{print "-e s/"$1"/"$2"}'`<<< "File1.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}; a[$1] {$1=a[$1]} 1' File2 File1
ID1 36987
ID2 75685
ID3 12345
id4 12896
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `sed` to generate the `sed` script:

```
sed 's=^=s/=;s= =/=;s=$=/=' File2 | sed -f- File1
```